# Angular material - how to change pagination pages box color

Tags: angular, angular-material, pagination

ho how to change the color of pagination drop down ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fs7C9.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML:

```
<mat-paginator
    (page)="handlePageEvent($event)"
    [length]="length"
    [pageSize]="pageSize"
    [showFirstLastButtons]="showFirstLastButtons"
    [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions" //You need this option
    [pageIndex]="pageIndex"
    aria-label="Select page">
</mat-paginator>
```

In your class:

```
  length = 500;
  pageSize = 10;
  pageIndex = 0;
  pageSizeOptions = [5, 10, 25, 100]; //You need this
  showFirstLastButtons = true;

//And this method to change page size
  handlePageEvent(event: PageEvent) {
    this.length = event.length;
    this.pageSize = event.pageSize;
    this.pageIndex = event.pageIndex;
  }
```